# RALT doesn't send Alt_R

Tags: keyboard, xkb

I've tried remapping left Control key to left Alt key. in `/usr/share/X11/xkb/keycodes/evdev` by doing this:

```
    // <LALT> = 64;
    // <RCTL> = 105;
    // <LCTL> = 37;
    // <RALT> = 108;
    <LALT> = 64;
    <LCTL> = 133;
    <RCTL> = 134;
    <RALT> = 105;
    <SPCE> = 65;
    // Microsoft keyboard extra keys
    // <LWIN> = 133;
    // <RWIN> = 134;
```

Now, unfortunately, when I press the key that should send the 105 code (`<RALT>`), `xev` shows that `Alt_R` isn't sent, instead, I see this:

```
KeyPress event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x1000001,
    root 0x953, subw 0x0, time 3699145, (1608,681), root:(1609,682),
    state 0x0, keycode 105 (keysym 0xfe03, ISO_Level3_Shift), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 92
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

How do I make it send `Alt_R`?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I kind of figured what went wrong. Maybe not quite, but I managed to get it to work.

So, in order to reset the keyboards settings I was running `setxkbmap`. I for some reason thought that running it without arguments will cause X to reload the keyboard configuration. Turns out that instead it probably set some other keyboard layout as a default, where right Alt was mapped to that weird Shift key. The setting also persisted if I restarted the display manager.

Eventually just running `setxkbmap us` fixed it.